# ViewData is null in view but not in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I'm filling my `ViewData` in my controller and want to use the items inside the `ViewData` in my view. But the list which is filled using `ViewData` is always null.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult OrderReport()
{
    FillBagelCart();

    return this.ViewPdf("Order report", "ReportView");  
}
```

`FillBagelCart` is a function which fills `ViewData["BagelCartItems"] = LstItems`;
I Debugged that and it's not empty.

View:

```
@{
 List<Tuple<BestelBagels.Models.Bagel, BestelBagels.Models.BagelType, int>> BagelCartItems = ViewData["BagelCartItems"] as List<Tuple<BestelBagels.Models.Bagel, BestelBagels.Models.BagelType, int>>;
}
```

When I am using this list, it is always **null**. So I have no idea what should be the reason?

Comment: what is ViewPdf? Where do you pass ViewData to View??

Comment: Inside the function FillBagelCart. Passing is just filling ViewData["BagelCartItems"] = LstItems. Right?

Comment: Are you sure that the type (`List<Tuple<...`) is correct? `as` will return null if the cast fails.

Comment: yes, I used it on another view, it works.